# Image will not blur

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, blur

I had a view load with an image that was perfectly clear, and upon calling and action would blur the image and display some text. However, in my process of making all the information being called from the cloud, the image blur seems to not work now. The original code that worked looked like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    source=[UIImage imageNamed:@"testIma.jpg"];
    imgView=source;
}
-(IBAction)Less:(id)sender{
    imgView.image=[source stackBlur:40];
}
```

and now I have it set up like so and it fails to work:

```
    - (IBAction) Less:(UISlider *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Slider:");
    __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"test"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if (!error) {
            MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            imgView.image = [MyPicture stackBlur:40];
        }
    }];
```

Does anyone notice anything wrong? I cannot seem to figure out why it does not blur anymore.

Comment: Did you verify that `MyPicture` is not `nil` after `imageWithData:`?

Comment: Are you updating the UI from a background thread? Don't do that. Dispatch the call to `-setImage:` back to the main thread.

Comment: Tim is absolutely right. You can only update view from the main thread. Try using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//you code here});

Comment: I am sorry I am still somewhat new to Xcode would you mind helping me out a bit more by elaborating on that?